# React Form validation using Zod, ZodObject & ZodType Error

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

```js
import * as z from "zod";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import {zodResolver} from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";

const formSchema = z.object({name: z.string().min(1),})

type Schema = z.infer < typeof formSchema > ;

export const StoreModal = () => {

const storeModal = useStoreModal();
const form = useForm < Schema > ({
   resolver: zodResolver(formSchema), // here is the error in formSchema
   defaultValues: {
      name: "",
   },
});
```

error:

> Argument of type 'ZodObject<{ name: ZodString; }, "strip", ZodTypeAny, { name: string; }, { name: string; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ZodType<any, any, any>'

I looked over the official documentation and i followed it but its not working

Comment: This is an issue with zod. Downgrading the version to 3.21.4 solves it. Checkout this

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/2663